# respond.js not working on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, media-queries

There are many topics but I can't find solution for my problem so I hope everyone can help me. I tried many days, I put respond.js after all CSS but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
<style>
    .green{
        background: #2DFF78;
    }

    .blue{
        background: #02779E;
    }

    .col6{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="respond.min.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

**Tested on IE8 (by using IE9 and change browser mode on IE8)**

Answer (score 0):

We've got [`respond.js`](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) working with IE8 recently

It's for [`@media` queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

```
<style>
    .green{ background: #2DFF78; }
    .blue { background: #02779E; }
    .col6 { margin-bottom: 20px; }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) { .green { background: #ff0; }}
    @media screen and (max-width: 450px) { .green { background: #f0f; }}
</style>
```

You'll need to use @media queries in your CSS to make it work. [Check out their example](https://rawgithub.com/scottjehl/Respond/master/test/test.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself and it turns out that the minified version of the script gets corrupted in IE8, You should use the uncompressed version and make sure it doesn't throw any errors on the console.